# Summing different parts of a column in SQL

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I have a database extract in excel and want to create a custom value in Tablue using their create calculation, which I believe is SQL based.

Basically I have a large number of feeds which all show up different amounts in a column. For example:

```
feed 1

feed 1

feed 2

feed 3

feed 4 

feed 4

feed 4
```

And I want to have a sum for feed 1, feed 2, and feed 4. But in my actual DB there's about 100 feeds all with different number of appearances. I'm having troubles finding a good way to do this. If there even is one. Any help or direction would be appreciated!

Comment: select feed, sum(2ndcolumn) from table group by feed ?

Comment: could you show me how the output should be ?

Comment: Like SUM(feed 1) should be a continuous measure in Tableau and it's number is 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your list is a single column and you need a count of the number of occurrences of each feed. For the sake of example, since a column or table names were not supplied, let's call them colname and tablename.

```
select colname, count(*) as Ct from tablename group by colname
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to give an exact answer if you posted a small simplified subset of your spreadsheet. But assuming you have a column called "feed_name" which takes on values like "feed 1", "feed 2" etc depending on the row. Then the feed_name column should be a discrete dimension in Tableau.

Then just put the feed_name pill on a shelf, say the row shelf. And put the "Number of Records" field on another shelf, say the column shelf.

You don't need to write SQL to do this (or most tasks) in Tableau. It helps to understand SQL concepts and its very helpful to drop down to the SQL level when needed to solve tricky issues. But for most situations, you can just interactively explore the data by moving fields around and writing some simple calculations -- and let Tableau take care of generating the SQL necessary to retrieve the data needed to build the visualization you requested.

Tableau supports SQL and some NO-SQL data sources, along with some cubes too. It does that quite well and in multiple ways. You just can work more quickly and efficiently by using Tableau's visual based manipulations in most cases, and then drop to the lower level detail when needed. It just takes getting used to how Tableau operates.